# I didn't get anything in my recycler view when i select image from gallery to show in recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, .net

I am just trying to pick image from gallery and show in recyclerview but when i go to the gallery and select image it show blank recyclerview here is my code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == GALLERY)
        {
            if (data != null)
            {

                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                adapter = new ImageAdapter(imageArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                //ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter (data, MainActivity.this);
                //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                //Counter = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you adding data in your `imageArrayList`

Comment: Why do you people so adamant in completely recreating view layouts in response to something happening? Your layouts are static anyway, treat it so.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot add data in your `imageArrayList`

> **1.** this first add data in `Arraylist` than set `Adapter` to your `recyclerView`

```
imageArrayList.add( add here your data);
adapter = new ImageAdapter(imageArrayList);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: *set setLayoutManager before setting adapter to your recyclerView* Why do you belive that order of calling `setLayoutManager` and `setAdapter` matters? Is it somewhere documented or just your imagination?